# i have added a new system call and when i'm trying to compile the linux kernel i'm using v 6.6.8 it gives me : Error 2 here is the syscall

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

```
#include <linux/syscalls.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>

asmlinkage long copier_fich(const char \__user \*src, const char \__user \*dest) {
    char buffer[4096];

    int source, destination;
    
    int charLect, charEcri;
    
    source = sys_open(src, O_RDONLY, 0);
    if (source < 0)
    
        return source;
    
    destination = sys_open(dest, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666);
    if (destination < 0) {
    
        sys_close(source);
    
        return destination;
    
    }
    
    while ((charLect = sys_read(source, buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0) 
    {
    
        charEcri = sys_write(destination, buffer, charLect);
    
        if (charEcri != charLect) {
    
            sys_close(source);
    
            sys_close(destination);
    
            return -EIO; //erreurs des entrées et sorties
        }
    }
    
    sys_close(source);
    sys_close(destination);
    return 0;
}
```

Can i have an idea to reslove it

Comment: Could you post everything you've done to add a syscall (I mean headers, syscall_tbl, etc.) and a normal build log (especially error)? Code you linked above looks at least weird for kernel code

Comment: Your syscall will block until its long-running operation completes. This is not how syscalls are written.